# Unable to dequeue a cell when searching table view parse.com iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm trying to do a search function in my table view, to return objects from my Parse.com class.

I'm getting this error when I try to make a search in the UISearchBar:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier FeaturedTableViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
@interface DiscoverViewController () <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) PFQuery *query;
@property (nonatomic, retain) PFObject *category;

@end

@implementation DailyDiscoverViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];

    self.searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;

    self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray array];

    _categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
}

- (void)filterResults:(NSString *)searchTerm {

    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Projects"];
    [query whereKeyExists:@"name"];
    [query whereKey:@"name" containsString:searchTerm];

    NSArray *results  = [query findObjects];

    [self.searchResults addObjectsFromArray:results];
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    [self filterResults:searchString];
    return YES;
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)refresh {

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Categories"];

    [query orderByDescending:@"name"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *posts, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {
            //NSLog(@"%@", posts);
        } else {

        }

        [_categories setArray:posts];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [_loadingView stopAnimating];
        [_refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        if (section == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return self.categories.count;
        }
    } else {
        return self.searchResults.count;
    }
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        return 320;
    } else {
        return 52;
    }
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        _featuredObject = [_featured objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        DiscoverFeaturedTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DiscoverFeaturedTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        [(PFFile*)_featuredObject[@"picture"] getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            cell.image1.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        }];

        return cell;
    } else {

        _category = [_categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        DiscoverTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DiscoverTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.name.text = _category[@"name"];

        if ([tableView isEqual:self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView]) {

            PFUser *obj2 = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Projects"];
            PFObject *searchedUser = [query getObjectWithId:obj2.objectId];
            NSString *first = [searchedUser objectForKey:@"name"];
            cell.name.text = [first substringToIndex:1];
            cell.name.text = first;

            return cell;
        }

        return cell;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Well you didn't provide us with the most necessary information. Is your cell being built from a storyboard or from a nib?

Comment: It's being built from the Storyboard @PatrickBush

Comment: You could try this, I remember running into this exact issue and this was one of the solutions I tried: `[self.tableView registerClass:[SiteFileCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"FileCell"];`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can look this stack over flow post : [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19084274/xcode-unable-to-dequeue-a-cell-with-identifier)

K.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

**Try it on viewDidLoad**:

> YourCustomCell *yourCustomCell = [UINib
>   nibWithNibName:@"YourCustomCell" bundle:nil]; [self.tableView
>   registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

**Note**: Your custom cell must have a .xib of course.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, I remember running into this exact issue and this was one of the solutions I tried: 
`[self.tableView registerClass:[DiscoverTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"DiscoverTableViewCell"];`

However, I distinctly remember that this didn't work. It turned out I hadn't correctly connected the cells in the storyboard. Furthermore, make sure that the class of your storyboard cell has been changed to represent your cell's custom class.